# Send Lambda Handler Response Body As Stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, response, serverless-framework

It seems like there are a million questions related to mine, but none of the suggested solutions are working or are just different enough that they don't help me.

I have a UI with a download button where users can get zip files from S3, but in my lambda function that is supposed to accomplish this, I am getting multiple errors.

I have a working solution using Express, but I am now needing to use a Serverless framework instead.

Here is my working solution in the Express framework:

```
const zip = new AdmZip(data.Body);
const entries = zip.getEntries();
let newZip = new AdmZip();
for(let entry of entries){
    newZip.addFile(entry.entryName, entry.getCompressedData());
}
newZip.writeZip(__dirname + `/${file}.zip`);
let fileToSend = fs.createReadStream(`${file}.zip`);
fileToSend.pipe(res);
```

Where I use the AdmZip to essentially create a new zip file from the buffer that is downloaded and then send it to the response object as a stream which is definitely hacky but is working so I was happy with it for the time being.

I have tried a similar solution using the Serverless Framework and Lambda function that looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
       const response = {
          isBase64Encoded: false,
          statusCode: 200,
       };

       try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: decodeURIComponent(event.pathParameters.fileKey),
        };
        const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
        const zip = new AdmZip(data.Body);
        const entries = zip.getEntries();
        let newZip = new AdmZip();
        for(let entry of entries){
            newZip.addFile(entry.entryName, entry.getCompressedData());
        }
        newZip.writeZip(__dirname + `/${fileName}.zip`);
        var fileToSend = fs.createReadStream(`${fileName}.zip`);
        fileToSend.pipe(response.body);
       } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
         response.body = JSON.stringify({ message: 'Failed To Get File', errorMessage: error });
         response.statusCode = 500;
    }
return response;
};
```

But in using this code it creates the file successfully in the local directory but throws the error
**TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function**

Which I have looked into, and appears to be an issue with promises but I am quite ignorant when it comes to streams.

At this point, I would love to have someone help with either editing my existing code, or pointing me in a completely different direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `fs/promises` does not have `createReadStream` method, instead you need to get it from: `const { createReadStream } = require('fs');`, let me know if it solves your issue

Comment: I added `const { createReadStream } = require('fs');`
and implemented with
`let fileToSend = createReadStream(``${event.pathParameters.fileKey}.zip``);`
but I got the error: 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined**

Comment: what about using this code? `fs.createReadStream(__dirname + ``/${fileName}.zip``);`

Comment: @tam.teixeira that had similar results, but I think the problem has to do with "The response object must be compatible with JSON.stringify" (from AWS documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)). So I'm not sure where to go from here if it's a limitation of Lambda Handler

Comment: You must base64 encoded the file locally, you cant forward a stream directly unfortunately
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Answer (score 0):

Lambda now supports streaming via Lambda function urls. This doesn't work with API GateWay.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-response-streaming.html

Sample:

```
const pipeline = require("util").promisify(require("stream").pipeline);
const { Readable } = require('stream');

exports.echo = awslambda.streamifyResponse(async (event, responseStream, _context) => {
  // As an example, convert event to a readable stream.
  const requestStream = Readable.from(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(event)));

  await pipeline(requestStream, responseStream);
});
```